# Error installing NetInfo with an Expo Go app

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to use the [NetInfo library](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/netinfo/). I usually test my app via Expo Go while developing.

I've followed the installation instructions, namely:

- `yarn add @react-native-community/netinfo`
- `npx pod-install`

Then I try to use the library, eg

```
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
  console.log("Connection type", state.type);
  console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
});
```

When I try to run this app via Expo Go, I get this error:

```
Error: @react-native-community/netinfo: NativeModule.RNCNetInfo is null. To fix this issue try these steps:

• Run `react-native link @react-native-community/netinfo` in the project root.
• Rebuild and re-run the app.
• If you are using CocoaPods on iOS, run `pod install` in the `ios` directory and then rebuild and re-run the app. You may also need to re-open Xcode to get the new pods.
• Check that the library was linked correctly when you used the link command by running through the manual installation instructions in the README.
* If you are getting this error while unit testing you need to mock the native module. Follow the guide in the README.
```

In terms of package versions, this involves all fairly up-to-date versions as of time of writing (June 2023):

```
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.10",
"expo": "~48.0.15",
"react-native": "0.71.8",
```

Anything else to try here? I saw a comment on [this Github issue](https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo/issues/659) suggesting this would never work on Expo Go, but that's surprising since it's offered as part of Expo SDK 48, no?